# Is the Invariant Subspace Problem arithmetic?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, lo.logic

Invariant Subspace Conjecture: A bounded operator on a separable Hilbert space has a non-trivial closed invariant subspace.

Can this conjecture be reformulated as an arithmetic statement, that is, $\Pi^0_n$ statement for some n? (I tried to figure it out, but failed.)

EDIT: For what I understand from answers, it appears to be an open problem. As 
Emil Jerabek and others mentioned, the intrinsic complexity of the conjecture (considered 
as a statement in second-order arithmetic) is $\Pi^1_2$. Apparently, no reduction to lesser 
complexity is known. One may speculate about how much of a solution would be a reduction 
to $\Pi^1_1$ or $\Pi^0_n$, but I would rather not.

Carl Mummert pointed out an interesting possibility: whether the conjecture itself 
is true or not, its interpretation in computable analysis may be false. 
In this case, if I got it right, the only way to reduce its complexity is to disprove it. 
However, this obstacle would disappear if we are allowed to use set 
theory to prove equivalence, because computable analysis doesn't work there.

Thanks to everyone.

Comment: It’s $\Pi^1_2$, and I am quite skeptical you can reduce this complexity without essentially solving the problem.

Comment: Is there any weak axiom system over which ISC is known to be undecidable - say, $RCA_0$? (I believe, although I haven't really put much thought into it, that ISC can be reasonably stated in the language of second-order arithmetic.)

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Why not post an answer explaining it? This is a great opportunity to explain how these complexity calculations go in applications of descriptive set theory to other parts of mathematics. Those calculations are often confounding for non-set-theorists, and this kind of interdisciplinary question is a great fit for MO.

Comment: @Joel: Feel free to take the opportunity. There’s only so much procrastination time on MO I can handle.

Comment: OK, I wrote up something.

Comment: I think you misinterpret Carl's comment. Even if the conjecture failed in computable analysis, it would still be perfectly possible to prove the conjecture or to reduce its complexity in another way. It's just that such a reduction would need something stronger to prove than RCA_0 (which is a fairly weak theory with respect to problems of this complexity).

Comment: @EmilJeřábek, your comment is addressed to Alex's edit, yes?

Comment: @Joel: Yes, I’m sorry if that wasn’t clear.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: Wait, didn't I write it myself in the last sentence?

Comment: Well, I guess I am really complaining about the previous sentence. If you show that ISC fails in computable analysis, and that RCA_0 proves it equivalent to a $\Pi^1_1$ sentence, this implies *in* *set* *theory* that ISC fails. It does not disprove ISC in RCA_0 itself unless you can actually prove in RCA_0 that it fails in the computable world. On the other hand, disproving ISC in set theory does not imply that it is provably $\Pi^1_1$ in RCA_0.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I played with this a few years ago at http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/06/29/finitary-consequences-of-the-invariant-subspace-problem/ ; in the language of the analytical hierarchy, I was trying to lower the complexity of the invariant subspace problem from $\Pi^1_2$ to $\Pi^1_1$.  I didn't quite succeed, because I couldn't quantify universally over all second-order objects, but one can instead reformulate the problem as a universal quantification of an arithmetic sentence over all "barriers" (a class of finite sets of natural numbers that "block" all infinite sequences, see [Is there a name for a family of finite sequences that block all infinite sequences?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/29676/is-there-a-name-for-a-family-of-finite-sequences-that-block-all-infinite-sequenc) ).  Unfortunately, barriers (or more precisely, the property of *not* being a barrier, which is the relevant predicate when reducing to prenex normal form) are defined by a $\Sigma^1_1$ sentence, so this does not reduce the analytic complexity of the invariant subspace problem; but one can at least express this problem as an infinite conjunction of arithmetic sentences, one for each barrier.  (One has of course has to add the predicate of membership in the given barrier to the arithmetic language.)

(There is also a universal quantification over growth functions in my formulation, which is another second order object, but this does not significantly increase the complexity, being a simpler object than the barrier.)

Henry Towsner (private communication) has achieved similar such "finitisations" for any $\Pi^1_2$ sentence.

Comment: Thank you, this is interesting. Asking about "arithmetization", I too had in mind some kind of reduction to finite dimensions. Now it seems to me even more hopeless then I expected.

Answer (score 31):

It seems to me also that the assertion is naturally expressed by a
$\Pi^1_2$ assertion in second-order number theory, as Emil had indicated. Let me explain
how one can see this.

The basic issue here is that the natural expression of the
statement in the language of set theory makes direct reference to
uncountable objects, such as the space and the operator and the
closed subspace, and therefore cannot be said to be purely
arithmetic nor even projective.

But the point is that, nevertheless, one can use the separability
hypothesis to find a natural translation of the statement that
brings it into the realm of second-order number theory, the
context of much of [reverse mathematics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_mathematics), and in this way reduce
the complexity to $\Pi^1_2$.

In order to do this, one must translate the basic concepts of
separable Hilbert space theory to second-order number theory and
develop a bit of analysis in that context. In particular, the only
objects available in this context are countable, and so one must
represent the space, the operator and the subspaces ultimately as
countable objects. For example, one can represent the space by
providing detailed information about the countable dense set, such
as the metric distances on that set and the linear operations; and
one represents operators by how they act on that dense subset, and
closed subspaces by their projections of that set, and so on.
Everything is ultimately represented by a countable amount of
information in this context.

Avigad and Simic have written a beautiful account
precisely undertaking this project:

- *Jeremy Avigad and Ksenija Simic*, [**Fundamental notions of analysis in subsystems of second-order arithmetic**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.apal.2005.03.004), *Ann. Pure Appl. Logic* **139** (2006), no. 1-3, 138--184.

If you look there (chapter 9), you will find how they represent
the whole space, and they develop the basic theory of real
analysis in second-order number theory. Since they are interested
in the reverse mathematical aspect of the situation, you will see
that they pay attention to precisely which axioms of second-order
number theory one needs to develop the basic facts one wants when
working with separable Hilbert spaces. Closed subspaces are
treated in chapter 11.

Now, putting all this together, one looks at your statement, which
asserts:

- For every separable Hilbert space and every bounded linear
  operator on it, there is a nontrivial closed invariant subspace.

So we have universal quantifiers, followed by an existential
quantifier, and each of these quantifiers is quantifying over the
space of countable objects available in second-order number
theory. The properties of being (the code of) a separable Hilbert
space or an unbounded operator on such a space are themselves
arithmetic, and the encoding of these concepts into second-order
number theory is arranged with that in mind. Thus, altogether the
complexity is $\forall\exists$ in second-order number theory, or
in other words, $\Pi^1_2$ in the [projective hierarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_hierarchy), which is of course a few steps beyond arithmetic.

This is of course, an upper bound, since it is conceivable that
one could find a clever equivalent formulation with reduced
complexity.

And while this doesn't make the assertion arithmetic, nevertheless the $\Pi^1_2$ level of complexity means that the assertion will be invariant by forcing, on account of the [Shoenfield absoluteness theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absoluteness#Shoenfield.27s_absoluteness_theorem).

Comment: Very nice explanation, JD!

Comment: By the way, I suppose that one could get a natural arithmetic weakening of the assertion, simply by restricting to sufficiently simple spaces, operators and closed subspaces. For example, one could restrict attention to computably presented spaces with computable operators, asking for closed invariant subspaces with a given arithmetic complexity. I don't have a good analysis intuition whether such an idea would be fruitful, but this would result in an arithmetic assertion with a similar meaning as the original statement.

Comment: A slight simplification of the formulation of the problem, but unfortunately not a reduction in the $\Pi^1_2$ complexity, would be to omit the quantifier "for every separable Hilbert space", since you can always take the space to be $\ell_2$. (This doesn't help the projective complexity because you still have the quantifier "for every bounded linear operator".)

Comment: Nice answer! Is it clear (as in reasonably plausible) that "invariant" is not hiding extra quantifiers? If I'm careless, I might state the problem as $\forall$ operators $\exists$ subspace $\forall$ vectors in subspace...

Comment: That is an important issue, but it seems to be arithmetic, since you just have to say that the operator applied to any of the points generating the subspace is in the subspace (that is, in the closure of the points representing it). But this all involves only arithmetic quantifiers, since you're just asserting that all the approximations to the stuff you have is is arbitrarily close to the stuff you have. That is, quantifying over the subspace is not a second-order quantifier, since you're representing it with a countable dense subset, so you've only got to quantify over those points.

Comment: Thank you. I did not know about this article. It is awesome.

Comment: Nice :) One more thing may be worth pointing out. One may try to get rid of the existential quantifier by noting that the invariant subspace is almost definable: if $T$ is the operator and $u$ any nonzero vector in a nontrivial invariant subspace, then the closure of the span of $u,Tu,T^2u,\dots$ is also a nontrivial invariant subspace. However, this does not really help, as one still needs a second-order existential quantifier for $u$.

Comment: As a comment on my own comment (and somewhat related to Emil's): we can also formulate the ISP as $\forall T \exists x,y\not=0 (\sum_{n\ge 0} |\langle x, T^n y \rangle |=0)$. (Of course, I'm only considering $\|T\|<1$ now.)

Comment: Do we know that the statement in question is true in the setting of computable analysis? If it is not, then that immediately prevents it from being equivalent to any arithmetical formula, because every true arithmetical formula is satisfied by the model of second-order arithmetic with the standard natural numbers and only computable sets. Actually, every true $\Pi^1_1$ formula is true in that model. This is a standard method for showing that particular theorems are not expressible by excessively simple formulas.

Comment: Here "equivalent" means "provably equivalent in a sufficiently weak system", which is more or less what the question is asking. Of course every true statement is uninerestingly equivalent to $0=0$.

Comment: @CarlMummert Indeed, that is the question, and I alluded to this version of the problem in my "By the way..." comment above. It seems plausible that one might hope to make a counterexample in the computable realm, by some kind of priority argument that diagonalizes against the possible computable vectors $u$ generating a closed invariant subspace.